# Specify path to CustomDictionary file for StyleCop spellchecking

Tags: c#, .net, spell-checking, stylecop

Spell checking of the comments was added to the recent versions of StyleCop. It seems I can reuse my existing CustomDictionary file (that I created for FxCop) with StyleCop. SA1650 rule [documentation](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1650.html) does not say that it is possible. But in [release notes](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/downloads/get/386813) for version 4.7.39 I see

> Add support for specifying dictionary folders in the settings.StyleCop
>   file.

How do I configure StyleCop to search for this file in the root folder of my solution?

Answer (score 7):

In my case it worked when I specified the custom dictionary entries in the Settings.StyleCop file located next to the .csproj file.

```
<GlobalSettings>
  <StringProperty Name="MergeSettingsFiles">NoMerge</StringProperty>
  <CollectionProperty Name="RecognizedWords">
    <Value>word1</Value>
    <Value>word2</Value>
    ...
  </CollectionProperty>
</GlobalSettings>
```

Actually, the StyleCopSettingsEditor.exe utility created these settings for me. I opened it using the project's context menu in Visual Studio, using the "StyleCop Settings" menu item.

Answer (score 6):

Add a file named `Settings.StyleCop` in your solution root directory with the following content:

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <CollectionProperty Name="DictionaryFolders">
      <Value>**my-dictionary-folder**</Value>
    </CollectionProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

Where you replace `my-dictionary-folder` with the relative path to the folder containing your CustomDictionary.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the StyleCop documentation for rule [SA1650](http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1650.html)

> The CustomDictionary.xml file should be placed in the same folder as the StyleCop.dll and the Rules. That folder (and all subfolders) are checked for the dictionary files.
>   StyleCop loads CustomDictionary.xml, CustomDictionary.en-GB.xml and then CustomDictionary.en.xml (where en-GB is the culture specified in the Settings.StyleCop file).
>   StyleCop also loads custom.dic, custom.en-GB.dic and then custom.en.dic (where en-GB is the culture specified in the Settings.StyleCop file).
>   Recognized words can also be added to the Settings.StyleCop file using the Settings Editor on the spelling tab.

So it appears that you would have to put a copy of CustomDictionary.xml in that specific location rather than in the root of the solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked here http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7422 and there is an open ticket here http://stylecop.codeplex.com/workitem/7435 which I believe will provide what you're looking for if it gets done.